# PHP array of objects in JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working on an API to be able to feed some data in an array in JSON format using PHP.

```
$newArray = array();
$i=0;
foreach ($resultJSON as $i => $item)
{
    $newArray['result'][$i]['ISO'] =$item['ISO'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Country_Name']= $item['Country_Name'];;

    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Retail']= (int)$item['Retail'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Food']= (int)$item['Food'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Transportation']= (int)$item['Transportation'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Transportation']= (int)$item['Telecom'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Household_Goods']= (int)$item['Household_Goods'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Oil_and_Gas']= (int)$item['Oil_and_Gas'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Electronics']= (int)$item['Electronics'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Automotive']= (int)$item['Automotive'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Chemicals']= (int)$item['Chemicals'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Technology']= (int)$item['Technology'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Pharmaceuticals']= (int)$item['Pharmaceuticals'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Construction']= (int)$item['Construction'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Machinery_and_Equipment']= (int)$item['Machinery_and_Equipment'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Metals']= (int)$item['Metals'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Aeronautics']= (int)$item['Aeronautics'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Business_services']= (int)$item['Business_services'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Utilities']= (int)$item['Utilities'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Personal_and_recreational_goods']= (int)$item['Personal_and_recreational_goods'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Paper']= (int)$item['Paper'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Sector']['Other_services']= (int)$item['Other_services'];

    $newArray['result'][$i]['Current_Average']= (int)$item['Current_Average'];
    $newArray['result'][$i]['Forecast_Average']= (int)$item['Forecast_Average'];

    $i++;
}


$resultJSON = (json_encode($newArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
header('Content-Type: application/json iHYPERLINK');
echo  $resultJSON;
```

The people that I am building for have said that they would rather have an array of objects.

Currently the output is

```
{ "result": { "0": { "ISO": "US", "Country_Name": "U.S.", "Sector": { "Retail": 21, "Food": 34, "Transportation": 35, "Household_Goods": 39, "Oil_and_Gas": 50, "Electronics": 61, "Automotive": 49, "Chemicals": 51, "Technology": 67, "Pharmaceuticals": 62, "Construction": 54, "Machinery_and_Equipment": 57, "Metals": 39, "Aeronautics": 56, "Business_services": 54, "Utilities": 44, "Personal_and_recreational_goods": 45, "Paper": 33, "Other_services": 41 }, "Current_Average": 49, "Forecast_Average": 50 }, "1": { "ISO": "CA", "Country_Name": "Canada", "Sector": { "Retail": 1, "Food": 1, "Transportation": 40, "Household_Goods": 52, "Oil_and_Gas": 71, "Electronics": 63, "Automotive": 79, "Chemicals": 45, "Technology": 84, "Pharmaceuticals": 89, "Construction": 59, "Machinery_and_Equipment": 64, "Metals": 34, "Aeronautics": 58, "Business_services": 55, "Utilities": 46, "Personal_and_recreational_goods": 80, "Paper": 39, "Other_services": 47 }, "Current_Average": 55, "Forecast_Average": 56 }
```

However they have asked for

```
{"result":[{ "ISO": "US", "Country_Name": "U.S.", "Sector": { "Retail": 21, "Food": 34, "Transportation": 35, "Household_Goods": 39, "Oil_and_Gas": 50, "Electronics": 61, "Automotive": 49, "Chemicals": 51, "Technology": 67, "Pharmaceuticals": 62, "Construction": 54, "Machinery_and_Equipment": 57, "Metals": 39, "Aeronautics": 56, "Business_services": 54, "Utilities": 44, "Personal_and_recreational_goods": 45, "Paper": 33, "Other_services": 41 }, "Current_Average": 49, "Forecast_Average": 50 }, { "ISO": "CA", "Country_Name": "Canada", "Sector": { "Retail": 1, "Food": 1, "Transportation": 40, "Household_Goods": 52, "Oil_and_Gas": 71, "Electronics": 63, "Automotive": 79, "Chemicals": 45, "Technology": 84, "Pharmaceuticals": 89, "Construction": 59, "Machinery_and_Equipment": 64, "Metals": 34, "Aeronautics": 58, "Business_services": 55, "Utilities": 46, "Personal_and_recreational_goods": 80, "Paper": 39, "Other_services": 47 }, "Current_Average": 55, "Forecast_Average": 56 }]}
```

So they do not want the numbers showing but I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check the output of first json, it seems to be wrong in format

Comment: How would I check? I am using   $resultJSON=(json_encode($newArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)); Json_encode so I do not know what else to do. Sorry :(

Comment: Post the value of $resultJSON so i can see whats the input and how to format to your required output

Comment: The value of $resultJSON is the 2nd block of code listed as current output is. Would you like me to print_r and send that?

Comment: Don't use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`. Just pass no second parameter to your `json_encode()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the flag `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` and remove the plus counter `$++`. It should resolve your problem.

```
$resultJSON = json_encode($newArray);
```

> **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT**
>
> Outputs an object rather than an array when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the recipient of the output is expecting an object and the array is empty. Available since PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to encode array like bellow to avoid array key

```
$resultJSON = json_encode(array_values($newArray));
```